# How do I prevent the axis from changing the interval size in a chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, yaxis, lightningchart

In LightningChartJS when I hide the bar with the highest value the overall interval changes and the axis length is adjusted according to the highest bar on display. Though I have used setInterval the axis length changes.

```
 const axisY = chart.getDefaultAxisY() 
 .setMouseInteractions(false) 
 .setTitle('Number of Employees') 
 .setInterval(0, 70) 
 .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the Axis' ScrollStrategy you are using.

In your code, using `axisY.setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)` you're setting the Axis to always fit all Series inside the Scale - which will result in the behavior you described.

You should try using `AxisScrollStrategies.expansion`.

You can check all the available [AxisScrollStrategies](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.1/globals.html#axisscrollstrategies) from the API documentation.